# Merge Karma test results from two angular projects

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have one main angular project that contains angular tests. Inside of this i have a "shared" module, which is actually a BitBucket submodule that has it's own karma tests.
Whenever i run the `ng test` command on the main project client app folder, tests from both "projects" are started but the results are overwritten ( big project overwrites the submodule or vice-versa)
Is there any way to append the results in the same results-file?

Also, for the main project i'm using JUnit Reporter, this is my karma.config file from the main project :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
process.env.CHROME_BIN = puppeteer.executablePath();

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    customLaunchers: {
      X: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--no-sandbox',
        ]
      }
    },
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-scss-preprocessor'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
    ],

    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: false,
        timeoutInterval: 10000
      }
    },

    proxies: {
      '/assets/': 'src/assets/'

    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: '', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.x ml
      outputFile: 'karma-results.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
      nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
      classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
      properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
      xmlVersion: null // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
    },
    trxReporter: {
      outputFile: 'test-results.trx',
      shortTestName: false
    },
    reporters: ['junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_WARN,
usePolling: false,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['X'],
    captureTimeout: 6000000,//it was already there
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 1000000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 1,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 6000000,
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

The Karma config from the second project is:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DISABLE,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    captureTimeout: 6000000, // it was already there
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 1000000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 1,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 6000000,
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

What i don't get is how the second project knows to output on the same file as the first one and overwrites the content of the main project?

Also the tsconfig.spec.json file :

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I assume that all the spec.ts file are included here (including the 2nd project ones, considering it's path : ClientApp\libs\SecondProject....)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one main karma.conf.js file with the settings and one for every projects. In your case 2 additional karma.conf.js files that extends main karama.conf.js file.

see below example and check property coverageIstanbulReporter to set output folder
karma.conf.js

```
const { join } = require('path');
const { constants } = require('karma');

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        jasmine: {
            random: false
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir: join(__dirname, '../../coverage'),
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: constants.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
        customLaunchers: {
            ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
                base: 'ChromeHeadless',
                executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
                flags: [
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                    '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
                ]
            }
        },
        singleRun: true
    };
};
```

karma.conf.js for project:

```
const { join } = require('path');
const getBaseKarmaConfig = require('../../karma.conf');

module.exports = function (config) {
  const baseConfig = getBaseKarmaConfig();
  config.set({
    ...baseConfig,
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      ...baseConfig.coverageIstanbulReporter,
      dir: join(__dirname, '../../coverage/apps/project-A'),
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: So you are telling me that is no way to have them in the same file? i need two files for each result file?

Comment: This way you will have 2 coverage test results one for main project and one for the other. Do you need one karma file or one report?

Comment: I need one Result file for both projects .I mean i need the results to be merged in one file, is there any way?

Comment: why don't you use only one karma.conf.js and delete karma from other project? In tsconfig.spec.ts set which directories with tests to include.

Comment: I'll try to do that, also can you please check my updated question?

Comment: your both karma files have same output directory 'dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),' that's why the first report is overwritten.

Comment: ok, as i asked before, how can i append the 2nd results file to the first one in order to have everything in only one file?

Also the output directory that you are telling me is redefined in the JunitReporter section for the main project

Comment: contents of output folder are deleted after running karma. You can't append 2nd results file with your configuration. Only way to do it is to have only one karma.conf (delte project's) and then you have to include all tests.

Comment: I see. I've updated my question by adding the tsconfig.spec.js file. Isn't that containing all spec.ts files?

Comment: yes, you have to include folders from you project

Comment: How it will be the path considering the 2nd project path? Also which Key should i update : "include", "files" , both?

Comment: you should only update include key with path to tests to other files

Comment: And should i delete something from the 2nd project? because now 2nd project overwrites the main one ( i mean the tests results)

Comment: Just delete karma.conf.js

Comment: Thanks a lot man for your support, i'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: is the only one anyway ^^

Comment: @TrulyXax Even I include the project/../test.ts file and spec.ts from project, running nt test only runs 1 project not all which I defined in tsconfig.spec.ts file